# Unable to find the DaggerAppComponent and AppComponent classes in Android Dagger 2

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2, android-instrumentation

I am developing an Android app using the Android Studio and Kotlin. I am adding instrumentation tests into my project. What I am trying to do now is I am trying to inject mock dependencies into the objects using Dagger 2 in my tests. I am following this tutorial, https://code.luasoftware.com/tutorials/android/setup-dagger2-for-android-kotlin/. I installed the required dependencies by adding this in my app gradle dependencies section.

```
implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.15'
    kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.15'
    provided 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'
    kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.15"
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android:2.15"
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.15"
```

Then I added the following snippet before the dependencies section

```
kapt {
    generateStubs = true
}
```

I also added this as well.

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
```

Then in my custom application class, I am trying to use the DaggerAppComponent class.  Seems like the class does not come with the package.

[image]

What is missing in my installation and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use following gradle dependencies for Dagger :-
In version.gradle file

```
    def dagger = [:]
dagger.runtime = "com.google.dagger:dagger:2.24"
dagger.android = "com.google.dagger:dagger-android::2.24"
dagger.android_support = "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support::2.24"
dagger.compiler = "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler::2.24"
dagger.android_support_compiler = "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor::2.24"

deps.dagger = dagger
```

build.gradle of app module use following code :-

```
implementation deps.dagger.runtime
implementation deps.dagger.android
implementation deps.dagger.android_support

kapt deps.dagger.android_support_compiler
kapt deps.dagger.compiler
```

Please create a `MyApplicationAppInjector class

```
class MyApplicationAppInjector : AppInjector()  {
fun init(app: ApplicationController) {
    DaggerMyAppComponent.builder().application(app)
            .build().inject(app)
    app.registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(object : Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks {
        override fun onActivityCreated(activity: Activity, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            handleActivity(activity as AppCompatActivity)
        }

        override fun onActivityStarted(activity: Activity) {

        }

        override fun onActivityResumed(activity: Activity) {

        }

        override fun onActivityPaused(activity: Activity) {

        }

        override fun onActivityStopped(activity: Activity) {

        }

        override fun onActivitySaveInstanceState(activity: Activity, outState: Bundle?) {

        }

        override fun onActivityDestroyed(activity: Activity) {

        }
    })
}
}
```

Create MyAppComponent interface as :-

```
 @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Singleton
@Component(
        modules = [
            AndroidInjectionModule::class,
)
interface MyAppComponent {
    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {
        @BindsInstance
        fun application(application: Application): Builder
        fun build(): MyAppComponent
    }

    fun inject(app: ApplicationController)
}
```

create a class

```
open class AppInjector {
fun handleActivity(activity: AppCompatActivity) {
    if (activity is HasAndroidInjector) {
        AndroidInjection.inject(activity)
    }
    activity.supportFragmentManager
            .registerFragmentLifecycleCallbacks(
                    object : FragmentManager.FragmentLifecycleCallbacks() {
                        override fun onFragmentCreated(
                                fm: FragmentManager,
                                f: Fragment,
                                savedInstanceState: Bundle?
                        ) {

                                AndroidSupportInjection.inject(f)

                        }
                    }, true
            )
}
```

}

and in onCreate() method of your application class 
use this code :-

```
`MyApplicationAppInjector().init(this)``
```

I hope it will fix your problem

Comment: Thanks. This is really helpful. I solved the problem after following this tutorial, https://medium.com/@elye.project/dagger-2-for-dummies-in-kotlin-with-one-page-simple-code-project-618a5f9f2fe8. That gave me an understanding of how dagger works in Android.